# Search and update array based on key

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two array, need to update the second array by searching the position in the first array.

```
let arr1 = [{"LEVEL":4,"POSITION":"RGM"},{"LEVEL":5,"POSITION":"GM"},{"LEVEL":5,"POSITION":"GMH"}]

let arr2 = [{"EMAIL":"test1@stc.com","POSITION":"GM"},
            {"EMAIL":"test2@stc.com","POSITION":"GMH"},
            {"EMAIL":"test3@stc.com","POSITION":"RGM"},
            {"EMAIL":"test3@CSR.COM.AU","POSITION":"GM"}]
```

**Output Array**

```
 output  = [ {"LEVEL":5,"EMAIL":"test1@stc.com","POSITION":"GM"}, 
                {"LEVEL":5,"EMAIL":"test2@stc.com",""POSITION":"GMH"}, 
                {"LEVEL":4,"EMAIL":"test3@stc.com","POSITION":"RGM"}, 
                {"LEVEL":5,"EMAIL":"test3@CSR.COM.AU","POSITION":"GM"}]
```

I tried using the below code to filter but gives empty array, so not able to proceed further:

```
const output =arr1.filter((item) => {
  return arr2.indexOf(item.POSITION) !== -1 && (item.POSITION)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can use `map` to create a new array. There you can use `find` to get the proper `LEVEL` property for the current `POSITION`.

One smart solution can be the following:

```js
const positions = [{"LEVEL":4,"POSITION":"RGM"},{"LEVEL":5,"POSITION":"GM"},{"LEVEL":5,"POSITION":"GMH"}];
const emails = [{"EMAIL":"test1@stc.com","POSITION":"GM"},{"EMAIL":"test2@stc.com","POSITION":"GMH"},{"EMAIL":"test3@stc.com","POSITION":"RGM"},{"EMAIL":"test3@CSR.COM.AU","POSITION":"GM"}];

const result = emails.map(email => {
  email['LEVEL'] = positions.find(p => p['POSITION'] === email['POSITION'])['LEVEL'];
  return email;
})

console.log(result);
```

From [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) documentation:

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

From [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) documentation:

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for beginners:

```
let arr1 = [{"LEVEL":4,"POSITION":"RGM"},{"LEVEL":5,"POSITION":"GM"},{"LEVEL":5,"POSITION":"GMH"}]

let arr2 = [{"EMAIL":"test1@stc.com","POSITION":"GM"},
            {"EMAIL":"test2@stc.com","POSITION":"GMH"},
            {"EMAIL":"test3@stc.com","POSITION":"RGM"},
            {"EMAIL":"test3@CSR.COM.AU","POSITION":"GM"}]

function addLevel() {
    const resultingArray = [];
    arr2.forEach(itemarray2 => {
        const copyOfArrayItem2 = Object.assign({}, itemarray2);        
        resultingArray.push(copyOfArrayItem2);
        const itemArray1 = arr1.find(x => x.POSITION === itemarray2.POSITION);
        if(itemArray1) {
            copyOfArrayItem2.LEVEL = itemArray1.LEVEL;
        }
    });
    return resultingArray;
}


const newArray = addLevel();
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and map new objects with `LEVEL`.

```js
var array1 = [{ LEVEL: 4, POSITION: "RGM" }, { LEVEL: 5, POSITION: "GM" }, { LEVEL: 5, POSITION: "GMH" }],
    array2 = [{ EMAIL: "test1@stc.com", POSITION: "GM" }, { EMAIL: "test2@stc.com", POSITION: "GMH" }, { EMAIL: "test3@stc.com", POSITION: "RGM" }, { EMAIL: "test3@CSR.COM.AU", POSITION: "GM" }],
    levels = array1.reduce((m, { LEVEL, POSITION }) => m.set(POSITION, LEVEL), new Map),
    result = array2.map(o => Object.assign({ LEVEL: levels.get(o.POSITION) }, o));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is:

```js
let arr1 = [{"LEVEL":4,"POSITION":"RGM"},{"LEVEL":5,"POSITION":"GM"},{"LEVEL":5,"POSITION":"GMH"}]
let arr2 = [{"EMAIL":"test1@stc.com","POSITION":"GM"},
            {"EMAIL":"test2@stc.com","POSITION":"GMH"},
            {"EMAIL":"test3@stc.com","POSITION":"RGM"},
            {"EMAIL":"test3@CSR.COM.AU","POSITION":"GM"}]
            
let output = arr1.map(item => {
  item.Email = arr2.find(a => {
    return a.POSITION === item.POSITION
  }).EMAIL;
  
  return item;
});

console.log(output);
```